# Jump to definition of function or class in one of the include files?

Tags: c++, ctags, ide, gtags

Take the following sample code:

```
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    double a = -10;
    double b = std::abs(a);
    return 0;
}
```

When I place the cursor over `abs`, for example between `b` and `s`, I want to have a command which would make Emacs jump to where `abs` is defined in the `cmath` header. It's a `ctags` or `gtags` kind of functionality, but which allows to jump to definitions in header files that are outside of the project root directory. How can I do that?

Comment: You could generate a `ctags`/`gtags` tags database, system-wide, for your standard libraries (`/usr/include` and the like), and add that path to each of your project-based `ctags`/`gtags` configurations.

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates the direct use of `semantic` for jumping to tags.

Make sure you configured `semantic-c-dependency-system-include-path` right.

The following code displays the tag in another buffer.
You can adapt the code to jump to the tag if you really want that.
There should already exist something like that. But, I did not find it.

```el
(defun semantic-display-tag (&optional pt)
  "Display tag at point."
  (interactive "d")
  (unless pt (setq pt (point)))
  (let (analyze tag buf loc start pt)
    (when (and (setq analyze (semantic-analyze-current-context pt))
           (setq tag (semantic-analyze-interesting-tag analyze))
           (setq buf (semantic-tag-buffer tag))
           (setq start (semantic-tag-start tag)))
      (with-selected-window (display-buffer buf #'display-buffer-pop-up-window)
    (goto-char start)
    (recenter))
      )))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c , d") #'semantic-display-tag)
(easy-menu-add-item cedet-menu-map '("Navigate Tags") ["Display Tag" semantic-display-tag (semantic-active-p)] 'semantic-complete-jump-local)
```